# XPath 1.0 exclusive or node-set expression

Tags: xpath

What I need doesn't quite seem to match what other articles of a similar title are about.

I need, using Xpath 1, to be able to get node a, or node b, excusively, in that order. 
That is, node a if it exists, otherwise, node b.

an xpath expression such as :

`expression | expression`

will get me both in the case they both exist. that is not what I want.

I could go:

`(expression | expression)[last()]`

Which does in fact gget me what I need (in my case), but seems to be a bit inefficient, because it will evaluate both sides of the expression before the last result is selected. 
I was hoping for an expression that is going to stop working once the left side succeeds.

A more concrete example of XML

```
<one>
   <two>
     <three>hello</three>
     <four>bye</four>
   </two>
  <blahfive>again</blahfive>
</one>
```

and the xpath that works (but inefficient):

`(/one/*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'blah')] |  .)[last()]`

To be clear, I would like to grab the immediate child node of 'one' which starts with 'blah'. However, if it doesn't exist, I would like only the current node. 
If the 'blah' node does exist, I do not want the current node.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: +1 Interesting question and IMHO a very elegant solution for it. Could you elaborate on why you are concerned with performance in this case? Judging from my experience, performance loss in XSLT sheets results from other causes.

Comment: Hi. It's actually for a java application. The application uses xpath expressions (loaded from a configuration file) to extract values from an XML document. The application will receive many such documents every minute, so efficiency is important to improve (or even achieve) reliable thru-put.

Comment: If this is embedded into Java you would/could have control over the sub expressions by explicitly executing the second XPath only if the first one does not yield a result, wouldn't you?

Comment: Not really. I don't have control over the xpath users could write as configurations. And this is just one example/default configuration

Answer (score 1):

> I need, using Xpath 1, to be able to get node a, or node b,
>   excusively, in that order.  That is, node a if it exists, otherwise,
>   node b.
>
> an xpath expression such as :
>
> `expression | expression`
>
> will get me both in the case they both exist. that is not what I want.
>
> I could go:
>
> `(expression | expression)[last()]`
>
> Which does in fact gget me what I need (in my case),

**This statement is not true**.

Here is an example. Let us have this XML document:

```
<one>
  <a/>
  <b/>
</one>
```

*Expression1 is*:

```
/*/a
```

*Expression2 is*:

```
/*/b
```

*Your composite expression*:

```
(Expression1 | Expression2)[last()]
```

when we substitute the two expressions above is:

```
(/*/a | /*/b)[last()]
```

**And this expression actually selects `b` -- not `a`**  -- because `b` is the last of the two in document order.

Now, here is an expression that selects just `a` if it exists, and selects `b` only if `a` doesn't exist -- regardless of document order:

```
/*/a | /*/b[not(/*/a)]
```

When this expression is evaluated on the XML document above, it selects `a`, regardless of its document order -- try swapping in the XML document above the places of `a` and `b` to confirm that in both cases the element that is selected is `a`.

**To summarize, one expression that selects the wanted node** regardless of any document order is:

```
Expression1 | Expression2[not(Expression1)]
```

Let us apply this general expression in your case:

*Expression1 is*:

```
/one/*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'blah')]
```

*Expression2 is*:

```
self::node()
```

*The wanted expression* (after substituting Expression1 and Expression2 in the above general expression) is:

```
   /one/*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'blah')] 
|  
   self::node()[not(/one/*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'blah')])]
```